# How were data pipelines and workflows managed before Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to understand the need for Airflow by understanding the difficulty without it. I understand that airflow brings in the concept of DAGs for handling workflows and it really makes sense, but I would like to understand how Workflows were managed before Airflow. I am trying to understand from the shoes of the founders who found the need for Airflow. Can someone point me to projects/frameworks use before airflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-airflow orchestrators broadly fit into one of two categories: less fully featured or tied to one application. Less fully featured but broad orchestrators include cron and windows scheduler. Many applications and ecosystems include their own scheduler, such as Informatica or Oozie (for Hadoop). This is fine until you have a workflow that crosses into something outside that particular application, which is very common.

As far as I know, none of these orchestrators allowed the kind of code based DAGs that Airflow did, so if they didn't support the kind of logic you were after in their UI, you were out of luck.